# Fail to deal with the filename in python 2

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have cloned someone's code from github and tried to run it but failed. The error points to this function:

```
# processing files in a directory
# return {b:'d:f d:f ...', ...}
def proc_dir(dwid_dir):
    bf = defaultdict(str)
    for fname in sorted(os.listdir(dwid_dir), key=lambda d:int(d.split('.')[0])):
        day_bf = bitermFreq(dwid_dir + fname)
        for b, f in day_bf.items():
            bf[b] += '%s:%d ' % (fname.split('.')[0], f)

    return bf
```

Specifically, this line of code:

```
for fname in sorted(os.listdir(dwid_dir), key=lambda d:int(d.split('.')[0])):
```

All the files' name in that dir is in a format like:`{int number}.txt`.For instance, `0.txt`.

However, it got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "bitermDayFreq.py", line 11, in proc_dir
for fname in sorted(os.listdir(dwid_dir), key=lambda d:int(d.split('.')[0])):
File "bitermDayFreq.py", line 11, in <lambda>
for fname in sorted(os.listdir(dwid_dir), key=lambda d:int(d.split('.')[0])):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

The author told me that he can run this code successfully. I wonder if this is about the issue of encoding. And how to fix it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you have any hidden files (in Linux), like say `.git`, it will cause this problem.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid You are right!!!! There is a file named '.DS_Store'. So i change that line of code to: `for fname in sorted(os.listdir(dwid_dir).remove('.DS_Store'), key=lambda d:int(d.split('.')[0])):` But got an error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` Do you have any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `.remove()` returns None (its an in-place operation). Use a filter as @falsetru demostrates in their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a file with a leading dot (`.`) which cause `d.split('.')` to return a list with an empty string as a first item:

```
>>> '.hidden'.split('.')
['', 'hidden']
```

---

To skip files with leading dot (hidden files in UNIX), replace the following line:

```
for fname in sorted(os.listdir(dwid_dir), key=lambda d:int(d.split('.')[0])):
```

with:

```
for fname in sorted([fn for fn in os.listdir(dwid_dir) if not fn.startswith('.')],
                    key=lambda d:int(d.split('.')[0])):
```

using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

---

```
>>> filenames = ['.hidden', '12.txt', '2.txt']
>>> sorted([fn for fn in filenames if not fn.startswith('.')],
           key=lambda d:int(d.split('.')[0]))
['2.txt', '12.txt']
```

Comment: Another case is if the directory is empty.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, If the directory is empty, the `int` will not be called.